# How to format the current system date to DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI:SS:AM format in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have tried quite a few methods to do date format in javascript but all that looked lengthy am looking for any short way to deal with this date format.
I want to change the `current system date` to `DD-MON-YYYY HH12:MI:SS:AM` format in javascript, has anybody have any idea on this.

> Forgot to mention: I do not want to use momento.js

Comment: ``let d = new Date();   
let date = d.getDate();
let month = d.getMonth() + 1;
let year = d.getFullYear();
let hours = d.getHours();
let minutes = d.getMinutes();
let seconds = d.getSeconds();
console.log(date, month, year, hours, minutes, seconds);``

Format accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

By using that cool moment library you can solve your problem like below code.

```
    var date = new Date();
console.log(moment(date).format('DD-MON-YYYY h:mm:ss A'))
```

Comment: without moment.js is asked by the question author.

Comment: I just tried using your method, i see month is coming wrongly, its coming like 10-3ON-2020 5:00:43 PM

Comment: @RajeshAcharya it is ``MMM`` instead of ``MON``

Comment: Thank you , it is fine.